# How to convert date String from JSON to time span

Tags: java, android, json, simpledateformat

The time value I get from JSON response is of format `"sun dd/mm/yyyy - HH:mm"` and I want to convert it to a time span instead (10 min ago, 2 days ago...). For that I made a method converts given String of dataTimeFormant into "`X Hours Ago`" format and returns `x hours ago` in a string format then I can put in a textView.

Everything seems correct, I think, but the app crashes on start with a NullPonterException to a line of my code, so probably I have made things wrong.

```
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public String dateConverter(String dateStringFormat) {
    Date date = null;
    SimpleDateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z");
    try {
        date = currentDateFormat.parse(dateStringFormat);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat requireDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDate = requireDateFormat.format(date);

    long currentTimeInMilis = 0;

    try {
        Date currentDateObject = requireDateFormat.parse(currentDate);
        currentTimeInMilis = currentDateObject.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    CharSequence timeSpanString = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(currentTimeInMilis, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

    return timeSpanString.toString();
}
```

My adapter onBindView method:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
  //...
  //...
  //...
        DateConvert converter = new DateConvert();
        String postTime = converter.dateConverter(this.news.get(i).getCreated());
        viewHolder.articleCreatedDate.setText(postTime);

    }
```

The logcat error points to:

```
String currentDate = requireDateFormat.format(date);
```

and :

```
String postTime = converter.dateConverter(this.post.get(i).getCreated());
```

I'm unable to find the cause because if I remove the call to that function everything works perfectly, probably there are better ways to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried breaking down the steps and examine your statement one step at a time? Is `this.post` null? Is `this.post.get(i)` null?

Comment: None of them is null. If I remove the call to converter.dateConverter() there is no crash

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.parse` returns `null` in case of error. Your `date` is null because the string does not fit your format. Check the API again.

Comment: Yes, like you pointed, the problem was about the pattern. I have made some modifications, but now I'm getting something like in the future with this pattern : ```EEE MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm``` took from android documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new here, hopefully I can help.

The first thing I notice is there is no closing single quotation after 'Z:

```
SimpleDateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Besides, the problem is the "currentDateFormat" does not portray the proper date input format which causes it not to be able to parse properly. If the input is "sun dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm" then the format should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM/dd/yyyy '-' HH:mm");
```

Or

```
SimpleDateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm");
```

Then `date = currentDateFormat.parse(dateStringFormat);` should be able to parse properly and the "date" will not have "null" value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already make the modifications, but the results is in the future. Today is April 4 2021. See the comments under my question

Comment: Oh, just figured out I was supplying the wrong pattern (again), needs to be ```"EE dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm"```

Comment: The date formatting is merely 'translating' what is being taken in as input. So it should be either the input is in the future itself, or the format is wrong. Glad you solved it :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciated it.